# O que significa o comentário de 3 barras em C++?

Tags: c++

Sei que existem basicamente 2 tipos de comentários, os de uma linha `//` e os multilinhas `/* */`, porem se eu comento com 3 barras até a cor do comentário muda, como por exemplo abaixo do Qt e do Visual Studio:

[image: Qt creator]

[image: Visual studio]

Se a cor muda deve haver uma razão para isso, então que tipo de comentário seria este?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No visual studio as 3 barras indicam documentação, não só comentário. É usado para adornar comentários que serão formatados especificamente através de seu editor ou alguma outra ferramenta como documentação para uma classe, método, namespace, etc.
Ou seja, após as 3 barras você pretenderia colocar a documentação do projeto ;)

Answer (score 8):

Se o comentário com 3 barras for igual ao do C#, eu acredito que é para documentar de forma que gere documentos XML.

Veja [neste link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2017) como inserir comentários XML para geração de documentação.

Answer (score 3):

Normalmente usa-se três barras quando for criar documentação para seu código. Você pode usar Doxygen para isso. [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)
Existem algumas tags específicas que são usadas para definir como o documento será gerado.
Abaixo deixo um exemplo de um trecho com as tags \brief, \param \return

```
/// \brief This metafunction converts degrees to radians.
/// \param T angle in degrees.
/// \return T angle in radians.
template <typename T>
constexpr inline T degreeToRadians(const T angle)
{
    return angle * ((PI<T>) / 180);
}
```